# I want to fetch user id of connected childs of user that is currently login. I am facing an issue that it is retriving all ids of all connected users

Tags: android

Unable to retrive current logged in user connected child ids from real time database

void getinfo() {
String userId = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
DatabaseReference dbref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Connection");

```
    dbref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                HashMap<String, Object> dataMap = (HashMap<String, Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();

                assert dataMap != null;
                for (String key : dataMap.keySet()) {

                    Object data = dataMap.get(key);
                    try {
                        HashMap<String, Object> userData = (HashMap<String, Object>) data;

                        String child_id = userData.get("Child").toString();

                        child_view_model_class child = new child_view_model_class();

                        child.setEmail("abc@mail.com");
                        child.setStatus("nhi lagaya wa");
                        child.setUserName("unknown");
                        child.setUserID(child_id);

                        childs.add(child_id);



                        

                    } catch (ClassCastException cce) {
                        Log.d("EXCEPTION", cce.getMessage());

                    }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UDTGf.jpg)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.